# Gdal memory leak but Anaconda won't let me upgrade to newer version

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, gdal, rasterio

I am trying to run some simple operations using `Rasterio` and `GDAL` but the memory leaks are just killing my computer. I just wanted to open and plot a `tif` file and it took about 50 GB!!! of Ram, even though the image itself is only 1.2 GB.

The code is pretty simple.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
src = rasterio.open("../temp.tif", mode="r+")
datimg = src.read(1)
show(src.read(1))
```

Here is a picture of the memory utilization in the middle panel. This is all RAM.

[image: Memory utilization]

So the process never actually worked, and now I have
to essentially log out and log back into my account on my computer to clear the memory.

I had gdal version 2.3.3 and rasterio version 1.0.21 installed, so I was hoping that person upgrading the gdal version to 3.0.1 might fix the issues.

I use the Anaconda distribution on python 3.7, Ubuntu linux 18.04 LTS. But when I tried to upgrade to the newer gdal version using `conda install -c conda-forge gdal gdal==3.0.1` I get errors indicating that there are incompatibilities with other packages.

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal gdal==3.0.1
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - _anaconda_depends -> mkl-service
  - anaconda -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py36he904b0f_5
  - fiona -> gdal[version='>=2.4.1,<2.5.0a0'] -> libgdal==2.4.2=h0845e09_2
  - gdal==3.0.1 -> libgdal==3.0.1=h0845e09_3
  - geopandas -> fiona -> gdal[version='>=2.4.1,<2.5.0a0'] -> libgdal==2.4.2=h0845e09_2
  - libgdal
  - pkgs/main/linux-64::importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0
  - pkgs/main/linux-64::mkl-service==1.1.2=py37he904b0f_5
  - pkgs/main/linux-64::path.py==11.5.0=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
  - rasterio -> libgdal[version='>=2.4.1,<2.5.0a0']
```

So I am not sure what I am supposed to do here? I can't keep logging out and back in to my account each time I run a command. The memory never releases, so if I run any rasterio or gdal command again, the entire system locks up.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Google Colab. It allowed almost 20 GB RAM as far as I remember a year ago. Try it in Colab, at least you'll be sure that your computer won't crash anymore. Another advice is, try a smaller map to observe what might go wrong.